# Nativescript registerElement with constructor arguments

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Can anyone help me with registerElement?  I'm trying to register an element that has services in the constructor.  I have the following code:

```
export class CardComponent extends ContentView implements OnInit{

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
    super();
  }
...
}

registerElement('app-card', () => CardComponent);
```

and I'm getting the error `error TS2322: Type 'typeof CardComponent' is not assignable to type 'ViewClass'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`registerElement` is designated to be used with NativeScript UI elements, anything that you might extend from the base `View` or any of its descendants (such as ContentView).

But these UI elements can not have Angular's life cycle hooks or dependency injections. I think you are trying to mix them up which won't be possible.

If you are willing to provide extensive Angular support for your custom UI element, then you should write a separate Angular component that might inherit the custom UI element. Something similar to [RadListView](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-ui-api-reference/classes/radlistview) vs [RadListViewComponent](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/api/classes/radlistviewcomponent.html).

Comment: If that is the case, how would I use an angular component inside the tns.html files?  I tried just including it but it was ignored, which is when I found out and tried registerElement.

Comment: For an Angular component, you just have to declare it in your module and use the selector in your HTML. If it doesn't work for you, please share a Playground where the issue can be reproduced.